# In $a - (a + 2)=-2$, how did the $2$ become $-2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm new to math. I would like to ask for you help to explain solving the following:

$$a - (a + 2)= -2$$

I didn't understand how the $2$ became $-2$.

Is there a good reference to learn these step by step?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $a+(-1)(a+2)=a+(-a-2)=a+(-a)+(-2)=-2$

Comment: For example, if $a=4,$ $$a-(a+2)=4-(4+2)=4-6=-2.$$

Answer (score 3):

The minus is distributive, like multiplying the amount in parentheses by $(-1).\space$ Expanding, we get.

$a-(a+2)=a-a-2\quad =0-2=-2$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps think of '$a$' as some other number like $5$.

$$5-(5+2)=-2$$

$$5-(7)=-2$$

$$-2=-2$$
Or think of using $10$ in place of '$a$'
$$10-(10+2)=-2$$
$$10-(12)=-2$$
$$-2=-2$$

In fact it does not matter what number is used in place of '$a$' the statement given is always true: if you subtract 'some number' minus 'two more than that number' you will get two less than you start with.

Answer (score 0):

I give you $a$ sweets

I give your brother $b$ sweets.

How much more sweets do you have compared to your brother? Well, $a-b$.

Now you found out that your brother has $a+2$ sweets. Well, it is $a-(a+2)$.  You actually have $2$ sweets less than your brother, not more. So $a-(a+2)=-2$.

By distributive law, we have $c(d+e)=cd+ce$.

$$-(a+2)=-a-2$$

Hence $$a-(a+2)= a+ (-1)(a+2)=a+(-a-2) = (a-a) -2=-2$$

where we use distributive law in the second equation  and associativity of addition in the next equation.

Comment: Thank you Siong... That explains it all!... If i want to dig deep in this subject and start from the scratch, what should I start with? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I think that depends on your background. If you are in secondary/ middle school, study the chapter about negative number and algebra.   If you are an undergraduate student, you might like to study algebraic structure such as ring/ field.

Comment: Kind of you lovely Siong... You are right I didn't have much math since high school. Do you think there are reliable websites to start with? Anything to start from the scratch upwards will be perfect!
Thnx for your time buddy!

Comment: maybe try the [mathpage](https://themathpage.com/aPreCalc/algebraPre.htm)?